# How to prevent OrientDB root user from accessing all databases

Tags: database, security, orientdb

We're using **OrientDB** in embedded mode. This creates a physical directory with the database on the client's machine.

The database has users and these are password-protected, however, this can be bypassed by clients. To by-pass, the client has to install the server version of OrientDB (on first run 'root' account would be generated), then copy database files from embedded directory to server directory and use the **OrientDB Studio**.

This means the database can be accessed using root account and this gives access to everything. I know OrientDB offers data encryption but this feels like a part solution to the problem.

So coming to question, Is there a way to prevent root user accessing and modifying the database by configuring database itself?
admin, reader and writer user passwords were changed to non-defaults. I am using OrientDB server: 3.0.16 and embedded 3.0.16.

Answer (score 0):

If database is encrypted then user root password no longer works.